# I have to add bx slider js in below require js for magento 2 ? I want to implement bx slider also

Tags: requirejs, magento2

```
var config = {
  // dependency order if applicable
  "shim": {
   "owlcarousel/minjs": ["jquery"]  
  },
  'paths': {
   'owlcarousel/minjs': 'Plazathemes_Loadjs/js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min'   
  }
 };
```

**I want to add bx slider as well as owl on my page**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly use  below code for adding the bX slider js  with this require-js

```
var config = {
 // dependency order if applicable
 "shim": {
  "owlcarousel/minjs": ["jquery"],
  "bxslider/minjs": ["jquery"]
 },
 'paths': {
  'owlcarousel/minjs': 'Plazathemes_Loadjs/js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min',
  'bxslider/minjs':    'Plazathemes_Loadjs/js/bx-slider/jquery.bxslider.min'
 }
};
```